# What is, in your opinion, the best publication on environmental and climate news?

Tags: discussion

What is, in your opinion, the best publication on environmental and climate news? I enjoy reading BBC Future articles about sustainable technologies and solutions (like this [one](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20210423-kenyas-unusual-solution-to-illegal-poaching-and-logging)). I often discover new, exciting things reading it. But it's not enough. What freely available publication do you suggest that combines a thorough scientific approach with an easy-to-understand journalistic style (like [the Knowable Magazine](https://knowablemagazine.org), perhaps, but not the Nature journal that at times is tricky to comprehend)?

Comment: Hi Sergey, I'd suggest asking this question in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58749975#58749975) for Sustainable Living, where just about anything related to sustainability is on-topic. But here on the meta site we try to keep questions [on-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and related to the [Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com) question site.

Comment: @Nic It seems to be already there

Comment: You're right! All new posts on this Meta site are automatically cross-posted into the chat room.

Comment: @Nic So do I need to do something on top of that?

Comment: Only if you want to continue the discussion, that's the best place.